# Zoom on Linestring object in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, linestring, zoom, jquery

I'm using Leaflet and trying zooming on a LineString object from a geojson file.
Here is an extract of my file (with a lot of LineString objects):

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "day": "Day 1",
        "route": "A - B",
        "id": "a-b",
        "distance": "256 km",
        "profile": "img/profiles/route1.png"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            13.6184281,
            45.919077,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6184281,
            45.919077,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6186132,
            45.9190975,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6195585,
            45.9191768,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6198306,
            45.9191968,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6201896,
            45.9192233,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.620569,
            45.9192515,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6207494,
            45.91926939999999,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6213905,
            45.91933280000001,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6216616,
            45.9193558,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6224639,
            45.9194158,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6235211,
            45.9195027,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6241017,
            45.91955149999999,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6251088,
            45.9196336,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6253359,
            45.9196521,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6261509,
            45.9197173,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6271895,
            45.919803,
            0
          ],
          [
            13.6275854,
            45.9198347,
            0
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I click on a HTML element as follows,

```
<h4><a class="zoom-to-route" id="a-b">A - B</a></h4>
<h4><a class="zoom-to-route" id="b-c">B - B</a></h4>
```

I'd like to zoom to the corresponding line extent of my geojson file. I can access the geojson file, but I can't retrieve the whole set of coordinates in order to zoom on them:

```
$(".zoom-to-route").on("click", function(){
    var routeId = this.id;  
    console.log("searching routeId: " + routeId);
    var i = 0;  
    $.getJSON("data/routeHoliday.geojson", function(data) { 
        $.each(data.features, function (key, val) {
            $.each(val.properties, function(propertyKey, propertyVal) {
                console.log(propertyKey, propertyVal);              
                if (routeId == propertyVal) {
                    console.log("Found " + propertyVal);
                    var zoom = data.features[i].geometry;
                    console.log(zoom);
                    map.fitBounds(zoom.getBounds());                    
                }               
            });
            i++;
        });
    });
});
```

The console.log is as follows:

```
searching routeId: a-b
id a-b
Found a-b
Object { type: "LineString", coordinates: Array[5602] }
```

Comment: So I am assuming the problem is that this line: map.fitBounds(zoom.getBounds()); is not doing what is expected? can you print the zoom.getBounds() part also to the console?

Comment: @ylka Yes, I think the problem is in that line. The console is: 
TypeError: zoom.getBounds is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a polyline object from the coordinates and then get the bounds from that object:

```js
$(".zoom-to-route").on("click", function(){
    var routeId = this.id;  
    console.log("searching routeId: " + routeId);
    var i = 0;  
    $.getJSON("data/routeHoliday.geojson", function(data) { 
        $.each(data.features, function (key, val) {
            $.each(val.properties, function(propertyKey, propertyVal) {
                console.log(propertyKey, propertyVal);              
                if (routeId == propertyVal) {
                    console.log("Found " + propertyVal);
                    var coords = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
                    var geom = L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLngs(coords);
                    //or
                    //var geom = coords.map(function (pt) {return [pt[1], pt[0]]});
                    var line = L.polyline(geom);
                    map.fitBounds(line.getBounds());                    
                }               
            });
            i++;
        });
    });
});
```

If you're adding the geojson to the map, you could also attach the event handlers to each feature using the `onEachFeature` callback option, getting the bounds of the feature with `getBounds()`.

Comment: I've tried your code, but insted of zooming to the righ area (Slovenia), it zooms to Yemen, inverting latitude and longitude...

Comment: Sorry, forgot Leaflet uses (lat,lon) instead of (x,y). I added a map() to flip the coordinate order.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> var zoom = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;

```
$(".zoom-to-route").on("click", function(){
    var routeId = this.id;  
    console.log("searching routeId: " + routeId);
    var i = 0;  
    $.getJSON("data/routeHoliday.geojson", function(data) { 
        $.each(data.features, function (key, val) {
            $.each(val.properties, function(propertyKey, propertyVal) {
                console.log(propertyKey, propertyVal);              
                if (routeId == propertyVal) {
                    console.log("Found " + propertyVal);
                    var zoom = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates;
                    console.log(zoom);
                    map.fitBounds(zoom.getBounds());                    
                }               
            });
            i++;
        });
    });
});
```

See also the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#polyline).

Edit:
I don't know if the problem comes from having Z-coordinates. In this case, I would try to parse the geometry myself. Something like this:

```
var len = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0].length;
var minLong = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][0][0];
var minLat = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][0][1];
var maxLong = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][len-1][0];
var maxLat = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][len-1][1];
var newBounds = [[minLat, minLong], [maxLat, maxLong]];
map.fitBounds(newBounds);
```

Comment: I've already tried, but it doesn't work. In this case console.log is:
Array [ Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], 5592 more… ]
TypeError: zoom.getBounds is not a function

Comment: the problem could be the z coordinates. please see my edit.

Comment: It's not exactly the bounding box, but it works, thanks!

    `var len = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates.length;`
    `var minLong = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][0];`
    `var minLat = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0][1];`
    `var maxLong = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[len-1][0];`
    `var maxLat = data.features[i].geometry.coordinates[len-1][1];`    
    `var newBounds = [[minLat, minLong], [maxLat, maxLong]];`
    `map.fitBounds(newBounds);`

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but is the default question askers are referred to when asking about zooming on click.
Adding a simple answer for any one wanting to zoom on clicked feature in layer.

```
layer = L.geoJSON() # or whatever is the way you want to create your layer
layer.on('click',function(e){
  layer = e.propagatedFrom
  map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds())
})
```

This will work for each feature in your layer, based on its calculated bounds.